# How to log request headers within script mediator in Wso2 API Manager 3.2?

Tags: wso2, http-headers, wso2-api-manager, request-headers

I am trying to get all transport headers used when calling a specific API and log that for debugging, since we do not know what the name of the headers will be I want to log them all.

I know this can be done via a class mediator as well as by enabling wire logs but I am looking for an option to achieve this without having to do either of those.

I have tried using script mediator and then using: `mc.getProperty("org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS")` to fetch them from message context but it just returns null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a property with the name `"org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS"` from the default Context, hence it's returning null. You can't really access `TRANSPORT_HEADERS` from the `Axis2Context` within a `ScriptMediator`. Your best option is to write a class mediator.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up having to write a class mediator. Wanted to avoid it so there wouldn't be a need for a new library on the product but rather contain this specific use case to the single API that needed it (using script mediator) but as far as I can see it cant be done unless we know the headers we are looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Use get-property from the transport layer.

Only you need to know the name of the variables.

```
<log level="headers" category="INFO">
     <property name="inicio" value="------ begin -------"/>
     <property name="X_Teste_FOS" expression="get-property('transport','X-Test-FOS')"/>
      <property name="inicio" value="------ end -------"/>
</log>
```

Comment: The question clearly states they do not know the names of the headers. So this would not work unfortunately.